# Mounting local external hard drive on a remote machine

Tags: linux, mount, remote

I have an external hard drive, which stores extremely large files. This is LOCAL and is connected to my laptop/desktop.

I run many different programs on a REMOTE Linux server.

I need to use some of the large files (stored in the external drive) as input to the program(s) that will run on the Linux server.

One solution is to FTP the large files from the external hard drive to the Linux server and then run the program(s).

This often leads to the following two problems:

1. The server has space problems.
2. File transfer is time consuming.

I want to know if there are some alternative solutions by which the data stored on the LOCAL external drive may become visible to my programs running on the REMOTE Linux server.

Comment: you will always have file transfer time problems when dealing with hybrid local/remote systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can always share you external disk on laptop (NFS or anything else) and access it this way from remote linux server. 
Or fo inverse, mount on remote server and access from local... Hope it helps.

Comment: Probably I would be interested in the "inverse" case. Would you kindly give me more detail? I always SSH into the remote Linux server from a Windows laptop (or sometimes from a Linux desktop) and work. Regards,